# Ionic 3 - filtering a complex array

Tags: angular, typescript, filtering, ionic3

I tried filtring an array coming from a json with the structure

```
{ID: "2031", title: "title 1", image: "http://wwwsite.com/im.jpg", url: 
       "url...", Goal: "3000000", …}
```

my array name is 'loadedprojects' and here is th filtering function:

```
getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
      this.getloadedproject();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.loadedprojects = this.loadedprojects.filter((project) => {
        console.log( this.loadedprojects);
        return (project.title.indexOf(val) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
```

on html page:

```
<ion-searchbar  (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Preview page html:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let project of loadedprojects">
      <img  src="{{project.image}}" />
      <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>{{ project.title }}</ion-card-title>
        <p>{{ project.country }}</p>
      </ion-card-content>

      <ion-grid >
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6> {{ 'Goal' | translate }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 class="value-amount"> {{ project.Goal | number }} رق </ion-col>
        </ion-row>

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6> {{ 'Donations' | translate }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 class="value-amount"> {{ project.Donation | number }} رق </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6> {{ 'Donnors' | translate }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-6 class="value-amount"> {{ project.nbr_donnors }} </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <button ion-button block class="donate_button" (click)="donation_options(project.ID, project.title, project.image)">{{ 'Donate' | translate }}</button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>



    </ion-card>
```

The search system is not working for me

Comment: How did you show the results? Can you show the `html` page too?

Comment: Do you still have the issue? What `console log` say?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `[(ngModel)]="keyword"`.You can try as shown below.

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```